# Error: No component factory found for 'component'. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am getting the following error:

`Error: No component factory found for DropdownComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

I understand that I should add the component (`DropdownComponent`) to `EntryComponents`:

```
entryComponents: [
    DropdownComponent    
  ],
```

I added this to app.module.ts but I'm still receiving the same error.

I have created a [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-49wawt). 
If you open the console and double click on one of the grid cells, you will see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already added in the `app.modules.ts`, then you also need to add the `DropdownComponent` in the component's `entryComponents`, where you want to display. Like below:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'abc',
  templateUrl: './abc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abc.component.scss'],
  entryComponents: [DropdownComponent]
})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `then you also need to add the DropdownComponent in the component's entryComponents`, what is reason behind this approach..? Can you explain more about it..

Comment: within column-data.ts, I have added 
`
cellEditor: 'editComp'
`

and within af-planning-grid.component.ts (where the component will be used) 
`
frameworkComponents: {
        editComp: DropdownComponent
      }, 
`